# Bandit-like Algorithm to Optimize Parameters?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, mathematical-optimization, bayesian, ab-testing

I need an algorithm to optimize the time of the week that I show a message to a user to ensure the highest probability that the user will click the message.

When the message is shown, a database entry will be updated with the day/time and whether or not the user clicked.  The goal is to maximize the click through rate.

I am very comfortable with using Bayesian Bandits (also known as Thompson Sampling) (https://github.com/omphalos/bayesian-bandit.js) to optimize in the case of N discrete parameters, but I am at a loss on how to apply this to a continuous value.

I'm well aware of standard hill climbing algorithms, but I only understand how to apply hill-climbing in the absence of statistical noise.  Is there a simple bayesian way to do hill climbing that optimizes the exploration/exploitation tradeoff?

For bonus points, is there a method that can be generalized to multiple dimensions, so optimizing multiple parameters simultaneously to find optimal points in a multi-dimensional space?

Comment: One possible approach to your problem is to discretize time in a week (there are 7*24 = 168 hours and I doubt that you need finer granularity) and use discrete version of bandits.

Comment: Good ol' linear regression tolerates noise.

Comment: I agree that the discrete time approach could work in practice, but it seems like such a waste to ignore the correlation between adjacent discrete time slices.  I'm guessing there is an algorithm that doesn't have this information waste.

Comment: I've also stumbled upon the Metropolis algorithm and Gibbs Sampling.  These seem to be in the right direction.  Does anyone have real-world advice on using a bandit approach versus the above mentioned algorithms?

Comment: Metropolis algorithm and Gibbs sampler are methods for exploring the posterior distributions of variables when there is no analytic expression for the quantity of interest. Depending on what you end up assuming for the structure of the reward function you may need them, but first you need to figure out what the variables are and how they relate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you view the reward function as a Gaussian Process to make this nice and Bayesian in the presence of continuous parameters. Essentially you have a regression problem where payoff(t) is a function to be estimated for continuous t, and you want a strategy for picking values of t which trades off exploration (regions of function space with high posterior variance) with exploitation (regions of function space with high expectation).

There's prior work on this, for example [this paper](http://las.ethz.ch/files/srinivas10gaussian.pdf) and other works by the author.

Comment: The paper, while hinting of something interesting, unfortunately provided no details of how to implement such an algorithm. Are you aware of any other references?

Comment: You could try the following: http://las.ethz.ch/files/desautels12parallelizing.pdf. Are you struggling with the implementation of a GP, or how to use a regression model for the reward function? These are in some sense orthogonal problems

Comment: Since I had never come across the term "Gaussian Process" before, I didn't register that it had any specific meaning.  I'm diving deep into the GP material right now, but gosh it is dense.

Comment: Yeah, if you're not used to non-parametrics then GPs are very hard to get your head around. There's a video lecture here: http://videolectures.net/icml09_murray_gpf/ - I've not seen this particular material but I was taught about GPs by the speaker and he's excellent. Also, focus on understanding how a regression model can be used as the reward function, and potentially you can fall back to a simpler Bayesian regression model which gives you uncertainty about f(x) as well as its expectation.

Comment: Here is the best GP intro video I've found so far - http://videolectures.net/gpip06_mackay_gpb/

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion to look at Gaussian Processes, I've found the answer I was looking for - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vz3D36VXefI

Comment: Here is an implementation in Python - https://github.com/fmfn/Bayesian-Optimization-with-Gaussian-Processes/blob/master/bayes_opt/bo/bayes_opt.py

Answer (score 4):

Closely related to Bayesian bandits are Bayesian mixture models. You can think of a Bayesian bandit as being a Bayesian mixture of [delta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). This removes the discreteness constraint. Instead, you can model the distribution over your continuous space as a sum of continuous valued random variables. For example, you could suppose that there are 5 "click sources", each with a normal distribution around the hour(8am, 9am,....), and that the standard deviation is 15 minutes. So, when you get a click at 8:05, you will attribute it heavily to the 8am model, a lesser amount to the 9am one, an even lesser amount to the 10am one and so on.

A commonly used algorithm to estimate mixture models is [Expectation-Maximization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation-maximization_algorithm). You should be able to find good open source implementations. Note that the above description(and EM) continues to hold in the multi-variate case.

Comment: This is a fascinating approach.  Is there any literature that details how much you allocate of the reward to each model?

Comment: Do the centers of these distributions move?  How does it figure out that 8:07 is better than 8:00 and show 8:07 consistently?

Comment: @JustinChapweske Try this [tutorial](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~lsong/teaching/CSE6740fall13/EMGaussianMix.pdf). The assumption is that the pdf you are trying to model lies in the (linear-)space spanned by the gaussian's you picked. As with most statistical methods, theoretical guarantees and convergence properties work nicest with gaussian distributions, but you might get good results with other representations.

Comment: @JustinChapweske In the mixture gaussian example above, the centers and variances of the gaussians don't move. So, the space spanned by gaussians with centers one hour apart might end up not being expressive enough. In general, the lesser the "curvature" of your pdf, the easier it will be to use such methods. If it is a reasonable approximation that points within 15 minutes of each other, say, will behave quite similarly, you can have a gaussian catering to such 15 minute stretches. If you have to worry about 30 second granularity, the space you are dealing with becomes correspondingly bigger.

Comment: @JustinChapweske Since EM is a general iterative method for maximum likelihood estimation, you could also try making the centers of the gaussians parameters over which you are trying to find max likelihood. However, such methods end up being sensitive to initial points when the search space becomes ill-behaved - starting near an adversarial local minima could kill you.

Comment: I don't understand this response. The objective in a bandit is to model the reward for each possible action. In the case of finite actions you estimate the expectation of the reward function for each action in a straightforward way. In the case of infinite actions (because the action space is continuous), you need a reward function f(a). Are you saying this is a mixture of Gaussians? Why? Assuming it's a probability density is odd since the reward function doesn't need to have probabilistic properties (integrates to 1, etc.)